# Is there any Custom ROM for the Acer Iconia B1-710 Tablet?

Tags: updates, custom-roms, tablet, rom

I have an Acer Iconia B1-710 Tablet (codename B1-710) with Android v4.1.2 and the following:

- Kernel: 3.4.0
- Image: Acer_AV051_B1-710_RV04RC01_WW_GEN1
- Cores: 2
- CPU: MTK 8317T, 1.2 GHz
- RAM: 1 GB
- ROM: 8 GB
- Stock ROM
- Rooted with Kingo Root APK
- Unblocked Bootloader

I would like to upgrade to a newer version of Android, but I searched in CyanogenMod, Paranoid Android, PAC-ROM, OmniROM, SlimROM, AOKP, Resurrection Remix, Dity Unicorns, XenonHD , BlissPop and MIUI without succes.

So, Is there any flashable custom ROM for my tablet?
If there's none, can I use the source to compile it?

Thanks.

EDIT: Haven't found yet a newer/custom ROM for B1-710. This is not a duplicate and this question hasn't been answered properly.

EDIT (2016-12-26):
Here is the DL link for [Android 4.2 (Jelly Bean) stock ROM (2013-06-10)](http://www.mtkfirmware.com/node/387) for the Acer Iconia B1-710 tablet from the Mediatek site.
The following ROMs **are not available** at this moment for device Tablet Acer Iconia B1-710:

- Replicant
- OmniROM
- AOKP (Android Open Kang Project)
- MIUI
- Aoikaze ROM
- And all the others mentioned above.

The following sites/forums **doesn't have** custom ROM information about Tablet Acer Iconia B1-710:

- XDA Developers (haven't searched throughly)
- Android Central Forums
- Samdroid Board
- Shipped Roms

Google *useful* links point to XDA that points to Acer Iconia Toolkit (useless to me without custom ROM) and to LolliAcer ROM (not a real flashable ROM that mostly bricks the tablet and in the best scenario only changes its appearence and does not update the kernel or OS version)

Taken form Acer Community:

> ---
>
> DannyK
> Troubleshooter
> Re: Iconia Tablets - Android 4.4 KitKat
> ‎12-23-2013 08:20 AM
>
> I read about that here:
> http://au.ibtimes.com/articles/530849/20131218/new-android-4-kitkat-upgrade-list-device.htm
> Message 6 of 18 (30,529 Views)
>
> ---
>
> inuya5ha
>   Die Hard
> Re: Iconia Tablets - Android 4.4 KitKat
> ‎12-24-2013 07:11 PM
>
> Acer Iconia B1 was released earlier this year (2013) and shipped with the obsolete Android 4.1.
>
> Had I known in advance that Acer would leave all their tablet customers stuck with Android 4.1 I'd have stayed as far as possible from Acer tablets. No wonder why all these devices ended here in LATAM countries with cheap prices, no other country accepted them because they knew they were obsolete the second they left the factory.
>
>  
> [sarcasm]
> Great news to see that Acer won't release ANY updates whatsoever to a device manufactured this year and still announced in their tablets home page today. I'll always be a happy and loyal ACER customer and recommend their tablets to all my friends and family without doubt.
> [/sarcasm]
>
> ---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a toolkit that I found that I haven't tested out but there is one here for that table, I think this might work http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2240029

Comment: Acer Iconia Toolkit doesn't fit my needs but, in that page, there are 3 links to a system image (stock and rooted) for Acer Iconia B1-710 / B1-A710 and the Bootloader Unlocker. Thanks!